# HTML/CSS Fluid Textarea inside table next to an Image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a layout where an image has a `textarea` positioned nicely next to it. The image may be of varying size, but I am going to force the image to be 450px high, and then have its width adjust automatically using CSS. I would like the `textarea` to fill the remaining space. I do not know the width of the image and I don't want to calculate it, I want the solution to be entirely CSS.

Can anybody in Stack Overflow heed my call?

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vo03yzzy/

I have tried using floats, but the closest solution came using a table.

HTML (just text):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            During winter ....
        </td>
        <td class='tdimg'>
            <img src='http://.....' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image: Just text, looks great!]

The pink cell (which contains the text) sizes itself so it is wide enough to fill up the remaining space  next to the image.

Now if I replace the text with a textarea, it doesn't look so pretty any more.

HTML (with textarea`):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <textarea>During winter ....</textarea>
        </td>
        <td class='tdimg'>
            <img src='http://.....' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image: with a textarea - what happened?]

The purple cell (which contains the image) now grows unnecessarily big.

This is my CSS:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}
td {
    background-color: #ffeeee;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.tdimg {
    text-align:right;
    background-color: #eeeeff;
}
img {
    height: 450px;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px purple solid;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline;
}
textarea {
    height: 450px;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:block;
}
table, td, tr {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

I have tried wrapping the `textarea` in a `div` with `display:block` - no luck. I've tried `position:absolute` and playing with `display`.

More details available at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vo03yzzy/

Help me Stack Overflow, you're my only hope!

Comment: Flexbox might do what you want http://jsfiddle.net/vo03yzzy/5/

Comment: mkaatman your example shows only text. I can get the layout fine with text; I need it for a textarea. Nevertheless, I will play around with flex box. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that does not involve tables?  I posted something that seems to work using tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the table layout, you can assign a width of 100% to the `.left-cell`, which will force the table to adjust the table cell widths such that the image cell has a shrink-to-fit width and the remaining width is allocated to the left cell (the 100% is more of a max then a specific width).

The advantage of the table layout is that the textarea cell will take on the same height as the cell containing the image, which may be desirable for certain layouts, depending on your design requirements.

```css
.container {
  background-color: seagreen;
}
table,
td,
tr {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  background-color: #ffeeee;
  vertical-align: top;
}
td.left-cell {
  width: 100%;
}
.tdimg {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #eeeeff;
}
img {
  height: 450px;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px purple solid;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline;
}
textarea {
  height: 450px;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-cell">
        <textarea>During winter, cold air masses from Siberia blow towards Japan, picking up moisture from the Sea of Japan in the process. The wet cold air collides with the mountains along the Sea of Japan coast, resulting in heavy snowfall. Some areas experience
          extreme amounts of precipitation with snow depths of three to six meters. Fittingly, Japan offers many popular destinations for snow seekers. While most of Japan's major cities, including Tokyo, Kyoto and Osaka, receive only small amounts of
          snow, locations offering snow experiences are readily accessible from them. The snow season in Japan is long and in some places begins as early as November and lasts into May, with the peak being in February.</textarea>
      </td>
      <td class='tdimg'>
        <img src='http://360niseko.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/igloo-snow-bricks_2012-03-26.jpg' />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The heavy, heavy use of tables should really be avoided if possible. Maintenance, usability, not to mention the semantic issues should set warning bells off in your head that say "don't do this! don't do this!" :-)

How about something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/1twng6L3/1/

Nothing too edgy like flexbox but does take some box-sizing into play to add some padding in.

Simple rules. Simple HTML.

```
<h1>Without the tables</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src='http://360niseko.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/igloo-snow-bricks_2012-03-26.jpg' />
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.col { 
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 425px; 
    padding: 0 2%;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
}
.col textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 420px;
    float: left;
}
.col img {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 425px;    
}
```

You might also consider the bandwidth of serving the full resolution image. I'm sure you'll take a different approach in your production code, it's wise to be careful about the bandwidth we're consuming with assets like that. Might kill any mobile or data-tied users.  (Just a thought)